# Getting a 2D slice out of a 3D ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I have generated a 3D plot of a surface using the `ParametricPlot3D` command.

Considering the three axes of the 3D plot to be `x`, `y` and `z` I would like to obtain a 2D plot showing surface boundaries for a specific `z` value.

Is there any relatively straightforward way to do that?

Comment: Why not use `ParametricPlot` with fixed `z` instead of `ParametricPlot3D`? If it's a problem of coordinate transformations, it would be good to see an actual example with code you have already tried.

Comment: Are you trying to impose the 2D plot on top of the 3D plot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Why is this getting flagged for being reopened? The issues haven't been addressed, and it's over a year and a half old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a way to get the 2D graphics from an already-generated plot.

```
tori = ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
     4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
     3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.1]];

With[{z0 = 4},
 RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeGraphics[tori], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{z0}},
   MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue]}, 
   PlotStyle -> None] /.
    Graphics3D[g_, opts___] :> 
     Graphics[g /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y}, 
      FilterRules[{opts}, Graphics], Frame -> True]
 ]
```

Animation from `Table[<plot code>, {z0, 0, 8, 0.2}]`:

[image: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehRni.png)]

Comment: Pretty neat this. Bit more on z range would make first torus vanish altogether... Can we also get a table of  x-,y- values for some z = constant section? Which independent variable is uniformly incremented in the section?

Comment: @Narasimham The z coordinate is increased (see `Table` code above animation).  The x, y values can be obtained with `Cases[regionplot, GraphicsComplex[pts_, __] :> pts, Infinity]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html).

Using the same example from the docs as [Zviovich](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1096/zviovich):

```
tori = ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
     4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
     3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];

Show[tori, ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, -1, 4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This seems a reasonable approach when computing the initial plot (`tori`) is expensive.

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
     4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
     3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < 4]], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u],
      4}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v,
     0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Using a combination of `MeshFunctions`, `ViewPoint` and `PlotStyle`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]},
  {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, z]},
 Mesh -> {{{3.5, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u],  4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]}, 
      {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
    ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity},  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, z]}, 
    Mesh -> {{{t, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
 {t, 0., 8., .005}, 
 AnimationRate -> 2, AnimationRunning -> False,  AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Also using Zviovich's example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{ConditionalExpression[{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
                  4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]},  Sin[v] < 0], 
  ConditionalExpression[{8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 
                       4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}, (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u] < 0]},
 {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 8}}, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Michael E2 possible to get x-, y- on Ver 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed Zviovich's doughnuts to manipulate at variable $x$ Box limited Toric sections.

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{{4+(3+Cos[v]) Sin[u],4+(3+Cos[v]) Cos[u],4+Sin[v]},{8+(3+Cos[v]) Cos[u],3+Sin[v],4+(3+Cos[v]) Sin[u]}},{u,0,2 Pi},{v,0,2 Pi},PlotStyle->{Yellow},Axes-> None, Boxed-> False,Mesh->{40,12},PlotRange-> {{0,xm},{0,8},{0,8}}], {xm,1,12,0.5}]
```

This may help to visualize 2D  "Almost"

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
   4 + Sin[v]}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 
   4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Yellow}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{xm - .1, xm}, {0, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "ALMOST_2D"]
```