# ParametricPlot3D Self Intersection

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I would like to know where my `ParametricPlot3D` 
intersects itself and to extract all intersections (points, lines, surfaces...) to animate them by changing `P`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{fX[u,v,P], fY[u,v,P], fZ[u,v,P]}, (* P is a vector of parameters *)
 {u,0,1}, {v,0,1}]
```

---

Example:
The vector `P` is not important, so here is an example from the documentation for [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html). The problem is to find the set of points where the surface intersects itself. In this simple case, the self-intersection seems to consist of two line segments, which I was able simply to guess by looking. What I seek is a more general method.

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]},
  {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#5] &)],
 Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, 
   Line[{{{1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}}, {{1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}}}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A small perturbation might serve as a working example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[u + 0.2 Sin[v]], Sin[u] + Cos[v + 0.2 Sin[u]], Sin[v + 0.2 Cos[u]]},
 {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}]
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of many duplicates, e.g. [(126847)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126847/equation-solving-intersection-of-graphs) and [(127161)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127161/find-where-a-parametric-equation-overlaps).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: That seem a duplicate due to the lack of information from my self:
- fX, fY, fZ are from Interpolation
Each time I use FindRoot, Reduce, NSolve Mathematica are not happy.
"Not valid variable, Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients..."
Thanks
PS: All answer I saw are on 2D that's why I post it again.

Comment: Having a simple working example will make it easier and more likely to get help.

Comment: @corey979  I think the OP is right that obtaining the ***curves*** where a parameterized surface intersects itself is significantly distinct from getting the ***points** where a parameterized curve intersects itself (as in the [current duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph)).  Would you agree?

Comment: @chkone I added an example.  Feel free to roll back or change if it does not seem appropriate for what you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

This 3D problem can be solved based on two 2D solutions, [76737](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76772/1063) and [33947](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33948/1063), by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2).  For the second parametric system in the question,

```
plt = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u + 0.2 Sin[v]], Sin[u] + Cos[v + 0.2 Sin[u]], 
    Sin[v + 0.2 Cos[u]]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#5] &), ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

generate slices for various values of `z`, for instance,

```
With[{z0 = .5}, RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeGraphics[plt], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
    Mesh -> {{z0}}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue]}, PlotStyle -> None] /. 
    Graphics3D[g_, opts___] :> Graphics[g /. {x_Real, y_Real, Real} :> {x, y}, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Graphics], Frame -> True]]
```

[image]

The points comprising the two curves then can be extracted from the plot, converted into `InterpolatingFunction`s, and `FindRoot` used to find the intersections.  To provide initial guesses, examine the plots above, provide an expression for the guesses, and then use `Nearest` to determine where those nearest points are on the two curves.  Finally, loop over slices in `z` to find the two lines of intersection, as follows:

```
pltdg = DiscretizeGraphics[plt]; tbl = {};
Do[guess = {sgn, 0}; Do[rp = RegionPlot3D[pltdg, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
    Mesh -> {{i}}, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None] /. Graphics3D[g_, opts___] :> 
    Graphics[g /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y}, 
    FilterRules[{opts}, Graphics], Frame -> True];
  pts = Cases[((rp // InputForm)[[1, 1]]) // Normal, Line[z_] -> z, Infinity];
  i1x = Interpolation[pts[[1, All, 1]]];
  i1y = Interpolation[pts[[1, All, 2]]];
  i2x = Interpolation[pts[[2, All, 1]]];
  i2y = Interpolation[pts[[2, All, 2]]];
  s = Quiet@FindRoot[{i1x[t1] == i2x[t2], i1y[t1] == i2y[t2]}, 
    {t1, First@Nearest[First@pts -> Automatic, guess]}, 
    {t2, First@Nearest[Last@pts -> Automatic, guess]}];
  AppendTo[tbl, {i1x[t1], i1y[t1], i} /. s]; 
  guess = {sgn Abs[i1x[t1]], i1y[t1]} /. s, 
  {i, -.96, .96, .01}], 
{sgn, -1, 1, 2}]
Show[plt, ListPointPlot3D[tbl, BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Red], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Addendum: Largely Symbolic Solution**

Because `Sin[v + Cos[u]/5] == z0` can be inverted symbolically to obtain `v` as a function of `u` for given `z0`, a faster and more accurate solution exists than the general solution given above.  First, obtain expressions for `x` and `y` as functions of `u` for fixed `z0`.

```
Clear[v]
Reduce[Sin[v + Cos[u]/5] == z0, v, Reals];
Flatten@Solve[Simplify[%, C[1] ∈ Integers && -1 <= z0 <= 1], v];
slice = FullSimplify[{Cos[u + Sin[v]/5], Sin[u] + Cos[v + Sin[u]/5]} /. # & /@ %, 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]
(* {{Cos[u + 1/5 Sin[ArcSin[z0] + Cos[u]/5]], 
     -Cos[1/5 (5 ArcSin[z0] + Cos[u] - Sin[u])] + Sin[u]}, 
    {Cos[u + 1/5 Cos[ArcCos[z0] + Cos[u]/5]], 
      Cos[1/5 (5 ArcSin[z0] - Cos[u] + Sin[u])] + Sin[u]}} *)
```

This expression gives the 2D slice at `z0` through the first plot above.  For instance, for `z0 == 0.5`,

```
Show[ParametricPlot[# /. z0 -> 0.5, {u, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}] &
    /@ slice, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

This plot is equivalent to the second plot above but has higher resolution.  A quick investigation shows that the two curves do not intersect in the vicinity of `z0 == 0.2`, as shown in this blow-up plot.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[# /. z0 -> 0.2, {u, 0, 2 π}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-.1, .1}, {-.01, .01}}] & /@ slice, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

The limits of the range of `z0` for which no intersections exist are given by

```
zp = z0 /. FindRoot[Thread[slice[[1]] == {0, 0}], {z0, .23}, {u, Pi/2}]
(* 0.236925 *)
zm = z0 /. FindRoot[Thread[slice[[1]] == {0, 0}], {z0, .16}, {u, Pi/2}]
(* 0.159385 *)
```

With this information the 3D intersection curve can be obtained.

```
eq = Equal @@@ Transpose@MapThread[#1 /. u -> #2 &, {slice, {u, um}}]
(* { Cos[u + 1/5 Sin[ArcSin[z0] + Cos[u]/5]] == 
       Cos[um + 1/5 Cos[ArcCos[z0] + Cos[um]/5]], 
    -Cos[1/5 (5 ArcSin[z0] + Cos[u] - Sin[u])] + Sin[u] == 
       Cos[1/5 (5 ArcSin[z0] - Cos[um] + Sin[um])] + Sin[um]} *)

tbl = {}; guess = .2;
Do[If[i < zm || i > zp, s = Quiet@FindRoot[eq /. z0 -> i, {u, guess}, {um, guess}];
    AppendTo[tbl, Join[slice[[1]] /. z0 -> i /. s, {i}]]; 
    guess = Abs[slice[[1, 1]] /. z0 -> i /. s]], {i, -99/100, 99/100, 1/1000}]
Join[tbl, tbl /. {z1_, z2_, z3_} -> {-z1, -z2, z3}];
Show[plt, ListPointPlot3D[%, BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Red], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

It agrees well with the third plot above except near `z0 == 0.2`, where the newly computed curve is the more accurate.  Computing it also is about two orders of magnitude faster on a per-point basis.

Comment: This is a nice approach but it does not really find the intersection curve, only a finite number of points on the curve with no connectivity information between them. Also, if I change the surface to `{Cos[u + 0.5 Sin[v]], Sin[u] + Cos[v + 0.5 Sin[u]], Sin[v + 0.5 Cos[u]]}` it gives some strange results.

Comment: @Rahul  The points accurately represent the curves, and they can be connected in the plot, if desired.  With respect to the surface in your comment, it is necessary to tune `guess` for each surface.

Comment: I see, it requires some manual intervention and some foreknowledge of where the intersections lie.

Comment: @Rahul  The foreknowledge is obtained from the second figure, which shows roughly where the intersections occur.

Comment: i think as a general approach you need to find the points then have a scheme to order/connect them. (the connection is perhaps worthy of a new question, but do a search first).

Answer (score 3):

@bbgodfrey's answer got me thinking that this could be thought of as tracking roots as a function of a parameter (here `u`), so I might be able to use a function I put together for that purpose [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358).  A self-intersection will be where `{x,y,z}=={x2,y2,z2}` for unique values of `{u,v}` and `{u2,v2}` (modulo 2π in this case).  That gives us three equations and four unknowns `{u,v,u2,v2}`, so treat one of the unknowns as a parameter (I'll use `u`), then solve for `{v,u2,v2}` as a function of `u`.

First, define `TrackRootPAL` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358).

Next, define two versions of the surface:

```
x := Cos[u + 0.2 Sin[v]];
y := Sin[u] + Cos[v + 0.2 Sin[u]];
z := Sin[v + 0.2 Cos[u]];

x2 := Cos[u2 + 0.2 Sin[v2]];
y2 := Sin[u2] + Cos[v2 + 0.2 Sin[u2]];
z2 := Sin[v2 + 0.2 Cos[u2]];
```

Find a starting point somewhere on the self-intersection using `FindRoot`:

```
u = 0.5;
init = FindRoot[{x == x2, y == y2, z == z2}, {v, 0.1}, {u2, π}, {v2, π}]
(* {v -> 8.24744, u2 -> 5.44587, v2 -> -5.41526} *)
```

Then track it with `TrackRootPAL`, which returns a set of `InterpolatingFunction`s:

```
Clear[u];
tr = TrackRootPAL[{x - x2, y - y2, z - z2}, {v, u2, v2}, {u, 0, 2 π}, 0.5, {v, u2, v2} /. init]
```

Thanks to @bbgodfrey's analysis, we know there is another set of self-intersections.  Repeat the above with a different initial point to find it:

```
u = 4;
init = FindRoot[{x == x2, y == y2, z == z2}, {v, 0.1}, {u2, π}, {v2, -π}];
Clear[u];
tr2 = TrackRootPAL[{x - x2, y - y2, z - z2}, {v, u2, v2}, {u, 0, 2 π}, 4, {v, u2, v2} /. init, NDSolveOpts -> {AccuracyGoal -> 6}]
```

Finally plot it all together:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -π, π}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x2, y2, z2} /. {u2 -> u2[u], v2 -> v2[u]} /. tr, {u, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x2, y2, z2} /. {u2 -> u2[u], v2 -> v2[u]} /. tr2, {u, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course this makes it look easier than it actually was.  The trickiest parts were 1) knowing how many disjunct sets of self-intersections there are and 2) finding good initial guesses to locate them.  @bbgodfrey's answer took care of 1) for me; 2) required some trial and error.  Maybe this could be automated somehow?

Comment: Elegant solution (+1).  Does your `TrackRootPAL` exist as a package?

Comment: @bbgodfrey No, I'm not confident that it's robust and well-formulated enough to package up.  It'd be great if more experienced folks gave it a careful vetting!